# Magento : Find_Feed Module

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, module

I have Find_Feed module in my 1.9 Magento store.

- What is this module for? i can't understand
- Is there a Magento2 version for this module? Examples ?

Could you answer me ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I found on the web about this module:

> Integration with [TheFind shopping engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TheFind.com)
>
> Current integration includes managing product feeds from Magento store to TheFind, mapping of Magento Attributes to TheFind structure.

It's marked as developed by Magento Core Team and looks like the third-party engine integration. If you do not use it, I'll recommend you to disable this module.

**PS:** TheFind shopping engine is no longer available, so feel free to disable this module.

**PPS:** this module was removed during update from the [1.5](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.5/app/code/community) to [1.6](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.6/app/code/community)